# not able to fetch bool value from contract using truffe

Tags: truffle, remix

Index.html:

```
<input id="txtUser" type="text" placeholder="Enter user name" />
<button id="btnAuthenticate" onclick="App.Authenticate()">Authenticate</button>
```

contract:

```
function Authenticate(string name) view public returns(bool){
    return false;
}
```

calling it from app.js: Tried all the below ways but no luck

```
// Import the page's CSS. Webpack will know what to do with it.
import "../stylesheets/app.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";

//Import Jquery files
import jQuery from 'jquery';
window.$=window.jQuery=jQuery;

// Import libraries we need.
import { default as Web3} from 'web3';
import { default as contract } from 'truffle-contract'

// Import our contract artifacts and turn them into usable abstractions.
import sampleartifacts from '../../build/contracts/samplecontract.json'

// MetaCoin is our usable abstraction, which we'll use through the code below.
var sampleinstance = contract(sampleartifacts);

// The following code is simple to show off interacting with your contracts.
// As your needs grow you will likely need to change its form and structure.
// For application bootstrapping, check out window.addEventListener below.
var accounts;
var account;

window.App = {
 start: function() {
var self = this;

// Bootstrap the MetaCoin abstraction for Use.
sampleinstance.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);

// Get the initial account balance so it can be displayed.
web3.eth.getAccounts(function(err, accs) {
  if (err != null) {
    alert("There was an error fetching your accounts.");
    return;
  }

  if (accs.length == 0) {
    alert("Couldn't get any accounts! Make sure your Ethereum client is configured correctly.");
    return;
  }

  accounts = accs;
  account = accounts[0];

  //self.refreshBalance();
});
  },

Authenticate:function () {
sampleinstance.deployed().then(function (instance) {
var normalusername="sampledata"      

    return instance.Authenticate(normalusername,{gas: 540000, from: web3.eth.accounts[0]}).then(function(v){
   console.log(v.toString());
 })
// return instance.Authenticate.call(normalusername,{gas: 540000, from: web3.eth.accounts[0]}).then(function(v){
//   console.log(v.toString());
// })
// return instance.Authenticate(normalusername).then(function(v){
//   console.log(v.toString());
// })
// return instance.Authenticate.call(normalusername).then(function(v){
//   console.log(v.toString());
// })
})
```

}
Below is the error:
[image]
Kindly help me in analyzing why i am not able to retrieve the bool value. Thanks.

Comment: What are `sampleinstance` and `instance`?

Comment: // Import our contract artifacts and turn them into usable abstractions.
import sampleartifacts from '../../build/contracts/samplecontract.json'

var sampleinstance = contract(sampleartifacts);

Comment: sample instance is bascially the contract instance, when it is deployed it returns an object and i call it as an instance.

Comment: By asking "what..." I meant that you should add their declaration and initialization properly in your question.

Comment: @goodvibration have updated as per your comment, let me know if you want me to add up with. Also help me out in figuring out the issue. Thanks